# Rails error: Couldn't find Node with 'id'=index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generate a node to show node name, but error . Here is the codo.

controllers/nodes_controller.rb (default)

```
class NodesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_node, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @nodes = Node.all
  end

  def show
    @node = Node.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @node = Node.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @list = Node.new(node_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @node.save
        format.html { redirect_to @node, notice: 'Node was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @node }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @node.update(node_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @node, notice: 'Node was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @node }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @node.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lists/1
  # DELETE /lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @node.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to nodes_url, notice: 'Node was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_node
      @node = Node.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def node_params
      params.require(:node).permit(:name, :summary)
    end
end
```

models/node.rb

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists
end
```

views/nodes/index.html.erb

```
<div class="nodes_list">
    nodes: <br> <br>
    <% nodes.each do |node| %>
      <button class="secondary hollow button tiny">
        <% if list.node %>
          <%= link_to node.name, node %>
        <% end %>
      </button>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :lists, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
  resources :nodes, only: [:show, :index, :create, :new] 

  root 'lists#index'
end
```

**rails s** http://localhost:3000/nodes/index

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NodesController#show
Couldn't find Node with 'id'=index

Extracted source (around line #61):      
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
60  def set_node
61    @node = Node.find(params[:id])
62   end

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"index"}
```

What should I do? How to debug? Thanks tell me.

Comment: You're going to the wrong route. The index is at `/nodes/`, the route `/nodes/index` is trying to render SHOW with an ID of `index`

Comment: Are you manually typing the url like `http://localhost:3000/nodes/index`?

Comment: Oh, My God. I Know. I am so careless.Now everything is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hit `http://localhost:3000/nodes/index` for the `index` action to be invoked in Rails controller. All you have to do is to go for `http://localhost:3000/nodes`, and it will hit the `index` action in your controller.

Anything like `http://localhost:3000/nodes/something` will take you to `show` action, and `something` will be taken as `id` to find a particular node. And since you are hitting: `http://localhost:3000/nodes/index`, so Rails is taking `index` as `id` to find a particular node.

Stick with the Rails convention, and REST principles, and let the magic of Rails take care of the things, and it sticks the following routes to particular actions:

```
GET: http://localhost:3000/nodes ----> Nodes#index
GET: http://localhost:3000/nodes/something ------> Nodes#show
```